# how to automatically creates a relationship

Tags: webform-civicrm, civireport, relationships

Is there a way to automatically create a relationship if 2 or more address in the DB is exactly the same?

I want to create the relationship if two or more people are living in same house.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a custom extension or module. 
in this extension or module, implement hook_civicrm_post()...

Drupal module's are the simplest, if you are integrating with Drupal that is

so for example

```
function MYMODULE_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
  // if location type  is Home (location_type_id:1), operation is create, and object type is Address
  if ($op == 'create' && $objectName == 'Address' && $objectRef->location_type_id == 1) {
    // look for other addresses with the same street address, city, state, postal code, zip, and country
    $result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'get', array(
      'sequential' => 1,
      'street_address' => $objectRef->street_address,
      'city' => $objectRef->city,
      "state_province_id" => $objectRef->state_province_id,
      "postal_code" =>  $objectRef->postal_code,
      "country_id" =>  $objectRef->country_id,
      'contact_id' => array('!=' => $objectRef->contact_id),
    ));
    if(!empty($result['count'])) {
      foreach ($result['values'] as $value) {
        // check for existing relationship between contacts
        $result1 = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'get', array(
          'sequential' => 1,
          'contact_id_a' => $value['contact_id'],
          'contact_id_b' => $objectRef->contact_id,
          'relationship_type_id' => 8, // change this to the id of the type of relationship you want to create
        ));
        $result2 = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'get', array(
          'sequential' => 1,
          'contact_id_a' => $objectRef->contact_id,
          'contact_id_b' => $value['contact_id'],
          'relationship_type_id' => 8, // change this to the id of the type of relationship you want to create
        ));

        // if no existing relationship found create the relationship
        if($result1['count'] == 0 && $result2['count'] == 0) {
          $create_result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'create', array(
            'sequential' => 1,
            'contact_id_a' => $objectRef->contact_id,
            'contact_id_b' => $value['contact_id'],
            'relationship_type_id' => 8, // change this to the id of the type of relationship you want to create
            'is_active' => 1,
          ));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```